# HTML layout with bootstrap

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get the desired layout as in http://jsfiddle.net/yFxea/16/ and the affect I am trying to achieve is on click of the "record" in the left, that attributes for that record to be displayed on right. But the attributes section's location should be the same for all records and as I click on each record the previous record's attributes should hide and display the current record's attributes. I was able to get the desired look and effect but what broke is the additional requirement that both the record content and attributes should be nested under the same DIV (or section tag).

I understand that this is not a bootstrap question but I don't want to break anything that bootstrap does.

Thanks

Comment: Could you provide more information. How are you changing the attributes values shown on the right? Is there any reason you have to use that layout? How are you generating the rows and records?

Comment: I am planning to use CSS(& javscript) to show hide the attributes section based on the row clicked. Per the design all the row(records) will share the same screen area to display the attributes. I am using Backbone js and will be using the underscore templates to create the records and that is the reason why both record content and attributes should be nested under a common DIV, to capture the events from the content and attributes using a single Backbone View.